# The way to run without flag in sed?

Tags: sed

I am studying for exam and,

**There was sample question like below:**

> Write a sed command that takes a phone number and changes the prefix
>   to 555 only for area code 111 and 222. Change all area code in parenthesis to XXX. ***Submit it as test.sed***

Thus I coded like below,

**test.sed:**

```
s/\(([0-9]{3})\)[[:space:]](111|222)-([0-9]{4})/(XXX) 555-\3/;s/\(([0-9]{3})\)[[:space:]]([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})/(XXX) \2-\3/
```

**file.txt:**

```
(123) 123-2345
(123) 111-2345
(111) 222-2345
(222) 333-2345
111 123-3423
```

**Output:**

```
(XXX) 123-2345
(XXX) 555-2345
(XXX) 555-2345
(XXX) 111-2345
111 123-3423
```

**Command I used to run:**

> sed -E -f test.sed file.txt

As I working on this sample question, I come up with that how the person who checks it check this. Because if it were real exam, I would just submit that test.sed file and I cannot tell him/her that he/she have to use -E and -f flag in order to test this program. But in reality there is no such chance to tell such thing in exam.

I just don't know the way how they check this in terms of their perspective. 
They probably run it by just typing sed -f test.sed file.txt but could miss flag like -E.

Is there a way to do this kind of stuff without using those -E -f flag? I tried not using those 2 flags then it just doesn't work. or does that question mean that do I have to make standalone .sed that contains -E -f flag? but is that possible?

Comment: since it was asked to submit as `test.sed` it would be known to use `-f` flag... as for `-E` you can use BRE instead.. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html.. or may be it is required to have `#!/bin/sed -Ef` as first line so that it can executed as `./test.sed file.txt`